# C function return not printing

Tags: c, function, return

I am pretty new at C and I tried to start writing functions because I will need this the most, however the return command in my functions seems not to be working, not sure if this is the cause.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int pega(int ppp);

int main() {
    int ui, marlin;

    printf("plotaaa\n");
    scanf("%d", &ui);

    marlin=pega(ui);

    printf(marlin);

    return 0;
}

int pega(int ppp) {
    int ju;
    ju = ppp+3;

    return (ju);
}
```

this is a simple function that should just get a number and sum 3 and then return that to the main function where I am trying to print.

Comment: Rule #1: indent your code.  Rule #2: do not use scanf

Comment: `printf(marlin);` -> `printf("%d",marlin);`

Comment: Use format specifer (%d) in the printf

Comment: Rule #3: Enable Warnings _and read them_.

Comment: Compile with `-Wall` and `-Wextra` and you will see what is wrong

Comment: Others have already pointed this out, but one of the "unfortunate" things (from the perspective of programmers spoiled by high-level languages) is that printf requires much more explicit direction than, say, Python's print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `printf` incorrectly, you need to pass it a format string as the first argument, and a value as the second argument.

Something like this:

```
printf("%d", marlin);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, as I said I am pretty new in C and it is very different from Python. Thanks

Comment: All the more reason to read the documentation of the function you use!